# Resteasy application always returning 404s

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy, java-ee-8

I started an application with only these two classes as a sanity test, but I only get 404s. I run a get request from Postman at localhost:8080/TestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT/test, which should hypothetically return "Hello World" but I get a 404 response. I'm using JBoss/Wildfly 14.0.0-Final as the server for reference. Any help would be appreciated. I'll include the two classes, the console output when deploying the server from IntelliJ, and the POM.

```js
<------------------- TestEntry.java ------------------------>
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class HealthyLivingApiEntry extends Application {
}
```

```js
<------------------- TestResource.java ------------------------>
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class HelloResource {

    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    public Response hello(){
        System.out.println("Running test service here");
        return Response.ok("Hello World").build();
    }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestApi</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.enterprise.concurrent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```html
20:08:41,174 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Estrella Galicia' 9.3.1.Final
20:08:41,411 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
20:08:41,862 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class TestEntry
20:08:41,865 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/TestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
20:08:41,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "TestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[2020-09-19 08:08:41,900] Artifact TestApi:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-09-19 08:08:41,900] Artifact TestApi:war: Deploy took 1,754 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing TestResource.java to look like below helped. Looks like for some reason a class isn't recognized as a  resource with the `@Path` annotation.

```js
<------------------- TestResource.java ------------------------>
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
public class HelloResource {

    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    public Response hello(){
        System.out.println("Running test service here");
        return Response.ok("Hello World").build();
    }

}
```